# How to remove extensions from Name column in FreeCommander

Tags: windows-explorer, freecommander

In order for me to switch from Total Commander to FreeCommander, I need to have an exact replica of the interface I've been using for almost a decade. I need to remove the extensions from filenames in the Name-Column.

This is how it looks in my FreeCommander:

[image]

This is how I need it to look:

[image]

Comment: Total Commander: often imitated but never duplicated! oh wait, TC is a clone of NC itself ... but you know what i mean :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest making a generous donation to the project, and then contacting them to request the feature.  You've provided screenshots, and it looks like a good idea that's simple to implement, so they might well oblige.

Otherwise, find an open source equivalent and code the features you need or hire someone else to code them.