# FreeCommander - how to "hide file extension"?

Tags: freecommander

as subject? In Window Explorer it's just a tick in "hide extension for know file type" but how can we do it with FreeCommander? I tried to add "HideExtension=1" in the .ini file but it doesnt work!
Many thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/60297/how-to-remove-extensions-from-name-column-in-freecommander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade to FreeCommanderXE, it has an option to do this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no option in FreeCommander to hide file extensions.  (I personally have never had a problem with this, but I was surprised when I noticed you could set up a column for file extension but not filename sans extension.)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it from profile settings. Right-click on a header in a tab and select `Profile settings`, then, `Modify setting`. You can tick the feature at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deep hidden option:

```
Tools/Settings/View/Column profiles
```

There, select a profile, then "Define columns" button (a hammer). There is open window where columns can be defined. The last check is: `Show extension in "Name" column.`

There "extension" for file name can be enabled or disabled.